# Faker not seeding db properly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, faker

I am trying to seed my db with faker. Everything gets filled out properly except images. They exist in my storage folders but are written in database as 0. Im quite confused and I've looked through the questions/answers provided here, but I haven't found the solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
   'title','description','image','price','category_id','user_id'
 ];
```

Factory:

```
'image' => $faker->image(storage_path('app/public/products'), 800, 800, null, false),
```

Migration:

`$table->string('image')->nullable();;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this `'image' => $faker->image(storage_path('app/public/products'), 800, 800, '', false)`

Comment: Funny thing is, i've tried this yesterday and it did not work.

But now it did haha. Thank you so much!